# Finding optimum point of parameters

Tags: cross-validation, optimization, parameterization

I have an algorithm with 3 parameters and sum of these parameters is equal to one; $a_1+a_2+a_3=1$ and each of them must be between $0$ and $1$. I want to find the optimum point for this parameters. The equation is a linear combination of these three parameters, $y=a_1 g_1+a_2 g_2+a_3 g_3$ and $g_1$, $g_2$ and $g_3$ are some known constants. If I use [k fold cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) to find the optimum point the space of search is very large because the dataset is large.

Is there any test method for such cases? If I want to search the optimum point for example by k-fold and by taking two of them constant and change the other, the space become large. Any suggestion? Is there better method for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it also true that each must be between 0 and 1?

Comment: @NickCox yes, I edit my question.

Comment: And the data is the sum of said linear combination, ie the regressand is $y=a1*g1+a2*g2+a3*g3$, $s.t. a1+a2+a3=1$ ?

Comment: @IMA yes,It's true.

Comment: Your search space is a simplex, specifically a triangle. There should be specific software for that.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks a lot for your attempt to help. My data is very big  and if for each parameter consider 10 case. I should run all my program 10*10*10=1000 times. I implement one complete program. I must obtain the best case that the program has minimum error. Do you understand me? if I use kfold for test my program it takes long time.

Comment: I don't know what kfold is, but this is a two-dimensional problem, isn't it? If you have values of two of the a's, the other value can't vary independently, as the constraint binds it. a1 = 0.1, a2 = 0.1, a3 must be 0.8, etc.

Comment: k-Fold refers to the cross validation mechanism he is using, it doesn't actually concern the problem other than that he has to run the algorithm he plans to use $k$ times.

Comment: Fatime, your system does require linear optimization of some sort. Can you use an external program? In that case take any programm which can do optimziations, such as GAMS, and minimize the sum of residual squares under the restriction of a simplex parameter space. There are programs which do specifically that. If you want to program your own algorithm, look into convex optimization problems.

Comment: @IMA Thanks, But I don't know i should minimize y or maximize it. I use y in other equation and finally make estimation.Then I compare my estimation with real value and obtain the error. I only want to minimize the error of my estimation that depend in this parameter. Do you understand me? What is the best cross validation or test method for my purpose?

Comment: 10 fold cross-validation with 0.1 increment gives about 1000 runs.

Comment: Fatime, what you are minimizing is the sum of residual squares: $(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2$ for each $i$, where the $\hat{y_i}$ is the result of the estimated parameter-equation given your input data. This formula is quadratic and can be optimized by finding the gradient, ie. regular convex optimization. There is a closed from solution. You need the program to do this under the parameter restriction. Still, this beeing a linear equation, you minimize the squared residuals which is a one-formula problem with your given restriction.

Comment: @NickCox Yes :).

Comment: Are you familiar with matrix notation of the ordinary least squares?

Comment: @IMA Do you mean something like this page? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares

Comment: yep, detailed below

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Nick Cox, your system is defined by $i$ observation and for each observation we have
$$y_i = \sum_{k=1}^{3}{a_ix_i} + error$$
Let's denote this by vector notation, $Y'=(y_1,....y_i)$ and  $X'=(x_1,....x_i)$ and then $A=(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ so we have:
$$Y = XA + \epsilon \\
\hat{Y} = X\hat{A} \\
e= Y-\hat{Y}$$
Your algorithm should then minimize not the $y$, but instead the squares of $y_i-\hat{y_i}$
$$argmin_{A} (e'e)  \\
= argmin_{A} [(Y-XA)'(Y-XA)] \\ s.t.  \sum_{k=1}^{3}{a_i}=1$$

Feed this into a program which can do this kind of stuff and do it k-fold. Without restriction, there is the usual closed form solution. With restriction I'd just use a numerical optimization program such as GAMS.

You might also want to think about cases when the solution is not unique, ie. if there is a weight you could assign the parameters which you would like to minimize "more".

Comment: Thanks for answer. I should describe the problem better. I obtain g1,g2 and g3 from the dataset. I should compute y as mentioned above.Then the dataset and y are the input to the system or the algorithm and I obtain estimated z. The error is  abs(real_z-estimated_z),not abs(y-y1).

Comment: What is z then? What do you estimate?

Comment: I have large dataset. I need some test dataset and some training. So I use k-fold. Each time I use one fold for test and remaining for training. The test dataset is the real values and from training dataset I should estimate the real one. My estimation depends on three parameters obtained from the training dataset such that the error abs(real_z-estimated_z) minimised.

Comment: Do you understand me in the previous comment?any suggestion?

Comment: I literally don't understand what you are even estimating, k-fold is just a procedure for cross validation. What are you using for estimation? What is the formula you use to gain this z? How does it relate to any of these parameters?